# Setup a web app using a gradle, spring boot and react

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to setup a spring boot web application with react. I tried to follow some tutorial, leading me to a code looking like this:

TechtoolApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TechtoolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TechtoolApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

IndexController.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}    }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    );
  }

}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/techtool
    username: root
    password: *********** 
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

My problem is that i'm always getting a WhiteLabel Error and I'm not sure why, even less how to correct my mistakes. Thanks fir helping me!

Edit: Added the directory tree

```
├───main
    ├───java
    │   └───com
    │       ├───Techtool
    │           └───TechtoolApplication
    │           └───IndexController
    └───resources
        ├───app
        │    └───App.js
        │    └───index.js
        └───templates
            └───index.html
```

Comment: What is the directory structure of these files?

Comment: Added the directory structure in the original post